# Has Yesod setMessage function a size limit?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm using Yesod and I'm experiencing a strange bug.
I'm uploading csv file and when the format is incorrect I display as a message (using `setMessage`) the uploaded file with some error message. When the file is too big, I don't get any message at all, as if I didn't set the message (or the message has been discarded).

I'm pretty sure the problem is on my side, but ss it possible that `setMessage` a size limit and discart too big message ? I guess `setMessage` uses session or something and it might have some restrictions .

Comment: All servers should check the request size. Check your `maximumContentLength` (on your foundation), default value is 2M (related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880105/efficient-large-file-upload-with-yesod)

Comment: The message is not that big, just a table about 8x5 cells ...

Comment: Ok, the default session backend is one cookie ~4Kbytes. Probably you should sent message into response or store in any backend to get back in future requests.

Comment: I'll have a look at that thanks.